# How to write my results in two rows of a .csv file in python?

Tags: python, string, list, file, csv

I have two lists one containing the file name and the other containing its corresponding value. I want to save the data in a CSV file. With the two headers: `Filename, value`. The below mentioned code saves the data in just two columns.

```
file_name = []
values = []

# And then when writing to file:
with open('./output.csv','w') as result_file:
    wr = csv.writer(result_file,delimiter=' ',quotechar='\\',quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    wr.writerows([file_name,map(lambda x: [x],values)])
```

Comment: When you say: "two headers: Filename, value" means one header with 2 columns?? Can you post example desired output?

Answer (score -1):

Use `zip()` to pair up the corresponding elements of the two lists.

```
wr.writerow(['Filename', 'value']) # Write header line
wr.writerows(zip(file_name, values))
```